# Can't understand why it is onErrorResponse which is "Something went wrong"

Tags: java, android

I want to have answer on onResponse but did not get it. I need guidance how I can achieve this.

This is my code :

```
public class Network {

    Context context;
    String pokemondata;
    CallbackInterface callbackInterface;

    public Network(Context context,CallbackInterface callbackInterface) {
        this.context = context;
        this.callbackInterface=callbackInterface;
    }

    public void test(){


        String URL = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("onResponse", String.valueOf(response));

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                callbackInterface.data("failure");
                Log.d("fail","failure");

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
   }

}
```

failure - OnErrorResponse which prints com.example.tablayout D/Data: My data +failure

onResponse data is "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"

Comment: You're suppressing the error. There's probably an exception inside the VolleyError (unless that is an exception itself, haven't used Volley in a while).

Comment: can you print the error you get from onErrorResponse()?

Comment: Can you update your code to log the VolleyError passed to onErrorResponse?

Comment: Response i get from onErrorResponse is :                   
 failure - OnErrorResponse which prints com.example.tablayout D/Data: My data +failure

Answer (score 0):

I have used String url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"; instead of String URL = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
Now it's working